Authorize external credential in partner community
In lightning experience a user can allow access to an external credential via OAuth through Settings > External Credentials. I'm trying to find a way for Partner users to do the same in a partner community, but the standard User Profile components don't have that option. Is there another way of exposing it or is the only option to build a custom component which utilises the ConnectAPI class to initiate the OAuth flow for each user?
